# How should I access log files on intranet servers (no public IP) with PHP?

Tags: php, intranet, logfiles

I have a system with multiple servers in a private network and web servers that have a public IP address and are also in the private network.

As part of the administration interface for the system, I have a log viewer, which was coded for a the infrastructure for a previous version of this system that all had public IP addresses.

The log viewer (written in PHP) allows an administrator to view the last n lines of (using tail -n) or search the file (using grep). It collates the log files from multiple servers and searches/tails the specified group of logs all together. I used to just use iframes to load the page on the individual servers, but now there are no public IP addresses, I'm not sure how to get the data. There can be quite a lot of it and a large number of logs opened in one go, as there is one log per thread of some scripts! The iframe approach was great because they all loaded separately, and I could see them as they came in.

I have full (sudo) control of all the servers.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Public or private the computers still have IP addresses.  There should be no difference (other than permissions) between //298.1.75.66/my.php and //192.168.1.5/my.php.  Can you give us a code sample that accesses log files across the network?

Comment: The difference is that the private computers don't have webservers installed on them